# Videoconferencing software that degrades framerate rather then resolution

Tags: windows, voip, conferencing

Is there a video-conferencing software that can be set to degrade framerate rather then resolution when the intervening connection is slow?

I do a significant amount of remote collaborative work. Right now, I am using skype, but when the network is slow between me and my co-worker, skype decreases the video resolution of the connection to try to keep the video fluid.
Unfortunately, this makes working remotely basically impossible. I rely pretty heavily on a mixture of screencasting & webcam video, and the low resolution makes the screencast effectively unreadable.

Is there a video-conferencing tool that will reduce framerate to maintain resolution, rather then reduce resolution to maintain framerate? If it slows down to 1fps, that is fine. 1fps at a readable resolution is better then an unreadable output.

Alternatively, are there screencasting applications that allow real-time remote collaboration, and can use a webcam as a source part of the time?